# tried to get a user from facebook with http.get

Tags: angular, http, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

i tried to get a user from facebook with the method "getUser" but i still get the error "property _backend is missing in typeof Http".
What is the reason ?

Here my code :

```
export class User {
    http:Http;
    constructor() {
      this.http = Http;
    }

    public createUser(user,token) {
        firebase.database().ref("Users/"+user.uid).set({
            name : user.displayname,
            token : token
        });
    }

    public removeUser(user) {

    }

    public getUserToken(id) {
        return firebase.database().ref("Users/"+id).child("token");
    }

    public getUser(token) {
        //let http : Http;
        return this.http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+token+"&fields=id,name,picture")
        .subscribe(data => data.json());
    }
}
```

i tried to make an instance from User and to call getUser here:

```
  export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,http : Http,public nav : 
  Nav,public loadingCtrl : LoadingController) {

  let me = this;
  let token;
  let user;
  let facebookUser;
  let userClass = new User();



  firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result){
      me.presentLoadingCustom();

      user = result.user.providerData[0];
      token = result.credential.accessToken;
      facebookUser = userClass.getUser(token);

      userClass.createUser(user,token);
      nav.setRoot(IndexPage,{user : facebookUser});

  });
```

}

Comment: Where is your http import statement?

Comment: import {Http} from "@angular/http"; above my class

Comment: Why are you trying to inject http to a class (model) along with class methods? Why not make a http.get request in a service and then just assign the data to your User model (interface or class)? Maybe check the docs: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 Keeping in mind they are using `HttpClient` there, but if you are using the deprecated HttpModule, here would be the docs for that: https://v4.angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6 As said, it's deprecated now (depending on your version of angular of course)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have injected `http` provider in your constructor.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
export class User{

constructor(private http: Http){

}

public getUser(token){

    //let http : Http;

    return this.http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="+token+"&fields=id,name,picture")
        .subscribe(data => data.json());
}
}
```

Also, you may be need to import `HttpModule` in `app.module.ts` if not already done like this :

```
...
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [HttpModule],
    ....
})
```

Comment: the problem is, when i inject the http provider in my constructor then i have to give the class "user" a parameter

Comment: ok. Can you share more code of your app ? How are you using User (and where) ? Please edit your post.

Comment: okay , i did it. i tried to make an instance in the class "HomePage"